# Select2 issue on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm encountering exactly this issue on mobile (I've tested on a iPhone 6) with select2

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4056

Is there a way to solve it or disable select2 on mobile? Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bugfix is still pending, so you can either wait for a fix or do it yourself.

To simply disable select2 on mobiles, you have to [recognize mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery) and only initialize select2 if none was detected.